# Semaphores in unmanaged code

Tags: c++, winapi, multithreading, semaphore

I've been using the [Semaphore class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to create semaphores.  However, the examples use managed code (requires /clr), and I need to use unmanaged code because it seems FreeType doesn't like working with managed code.

How can I create two simple threads which use a semaphore in unmanaged code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use native Windows [semaphore objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685129.aspx).

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for but could not find. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may try and use Boost.interprocess. It provides semaphores. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores).

Answer (score 1):

You want [CreateSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438.aspx) which is implemented in kernel32. The general pattern is to create a name or unnamed semaphore object to use from both threads. You can use [OpenSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684326.aspx) to get a handle to an existing named semaphore. Set the initial count and maximum counts on your semaphore appropriately then use one of the [Wait Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069.aspx) to take a logical lock on your shared resource by decrementing the count on your semaphore. When your thread has finished with the resource, call [ReleaseSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685071.aspx) to increment the available lock count.